# pg_ctl: server did not promote in time

Tags: postgresql

I setup a two node postgresql 10 cluster to test replication. Following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres-hot-standby)

I was able to get replication running correctly. However, I want to test the process of the slave to master. When I stop the master node, and run pg_ctl promote -D on the slave, I get:

> **pg_ctl: server did not promote in time**

I've looked online and can't find anything related to being unable to promote in time. After running the command and receiving the error, I have to manually start postgresql and it is still running in a read only state.

Postgresql is running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To promote, pg_ctl [writes a file](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__ctl_8c.html#acb36c999639e58671914856d3424f11f) called $PGDATA/promote, sends SIGUSR1, then waits a default of 60 seconds for the server to acknowledge that it is now read-write. Does that file exist? What is in the server log file?

Comment: Turns out the recovery.conf was owned by root and the postgres user couldn't open the file. Thank you for pointing out the log, I should have thought of that earlier.